# Can't see Methods, etc. in Visual Studio 2008 C# Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I typically code in VB.NET, but I'm going through a tutorial in C# .NET right now. I'm expecting to see a drop down list for selecting methods and properties at the top of the code file, right underneath the tabs for the code files I have open. However, I do not see these. If I open VB code, it works just fine. I've tried to look for an option in Visual Studio that I don't have turned on, but I can't find what I'm missing. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Do you get the keyword coloring when you open the C# file?  If not, then the CS files aren't registered correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->General and check "Navigation Bar"

Comment: Thanks! It was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the events, you can do it on design mode on upper border of the properties box, there is a "thunder" where you can access them, this part is different from that of VBasic

Comment: Wow.  I read that just like you did.  I think we completely missed his question, while Joel and womp nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

Tools Menu --> Options

Text Editor ---> C# ----> General  ---->  Navigation Bar  (check this box)

Answer (score 0):

Reset your entire environment. Tools--> Import and Export Settings... from this dialog you can reset your IDE settings, choosing to Reset all environment settings to one of the default collections of settings. (VB Developer, C# Developer, Web Developer, Project Manager...)